# ICCameraDevice cancelDownload doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm using the `ImageCaptureCore` framework to build a image view Application.

When I use `ICCameraDevice requestDownloadFile` API to download a large video form my iPhone, I can't cancel the download operation by calling the `ICCameraDevice cancelDownload` API.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by you can't ? What have you tried in terms of code?

Comment: @zcui93 I mean when I use `-[ICCameraDevice requestDownloadFile:options:downloadDelegate:didDownloadSelector:contextInfo:] ` to download an ICCameraFile to Mac, the delegate method called correctly. But when I call `-[ICCameraDevice cancelDownload]` method to cancel the current download operation there nothing happened. The download operation  is keep working till the operation done.

Comment: So, you've conformed to `ICCameraDeviceDownloadDelegate`? `didDownloadFile` & `didReceiveDownloadProgressForFile` was called in that delegate? Where did you call `cancelDownload`? Please add the actual code where you call `requestDownloadFile` and also `cancelDownload`. There's not information from your specific usage.